# Batch Files - How to check if there are multiple instances of a process running?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I was wondering how you would check if there are multiple instances of an executable running using a batch file, I have had a look at "tasklist" although there doesn't appear to be an option to do this.

```
E.g. if test.exe is running x2
echo program is running twice
else one of less instance of program running
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combination of wmic and find utilities seems to do the trick:

```
wmic process where name="test.exe" | find "test.exe" /c
```

At first we list all processes with name "test.exe", and then using the find.exe utility we count those lines. This command will return exact number of running processes with name "test.exe".

Comment: Thanks, though is it possible to do a if statement with this, maybe an error level statement. If = > 2 echo more than two. Or if < 2 echo less than 2 ?

Comment: Yeah, I think it is possible. You just need to save result of this command to any variable [refer to this thread for examples on how to do this](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/230090-45-windows-batch-file-output-program-variable) and then use if command to check its value.

Answer (score 1):

To save the variable you can use this:

set cmdcount="wmic process where name="cmd.exe" | find "cmd.exe" /c"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN (' %cmdcount% ') DO SET X=%%i

For some reason the X variable equals 2 when there is only 1 cmd file running but it still works because if you run the file 2 times x=3.